# How to pass byte[] list to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I got a byte arraylist(`List<byte[]> barray= new ArrayList<byte[]>();`).And i need to pass it to another activity.How i can do it with intent.putextra method or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this to populate the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra("barray_size", barray.size());
for (int i = 0; i < barray.size(); i++) {
    intent.putExtra("barray"+i, barray.get(i));
}
```

Then to get them out in the other activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<byte[]> barray = new ArrayList<>();
int size = intent.getIntExtra("barray_size", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    barray.add(intent.getByteArrayExtra("barray"+i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you can use a JSON serializer to accomplish this task. So you can convert from any (List in your case) to string and this is easy to serialize.